# Why does this PHP script show errors, but not echo etc.?

Tags: debugging, php

I have this PHP script http://snippi.com/s/kx0k48g (too long for here, but put it in Snippi). It is built to run by an AJAX GET request. When I supply all the right GET parameters the script seems to run fine (no errors), but it won't echo or anthing else that the script does (inserting in the Database). It only shows something (errors) when I do not supply the right GET parameters. Any idea what could be wrong? It is extremely hard to debug, because it won't tell me that anything is wrong, but refuses to do the right thing.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try calling `ob_flush` after your first set of `echo`'s.

Comment: @mellamokb Did not make any difference :(

Comment: Get a proper PHP debugger. It will change your life.

Comment: are you handling response from ajax request?

Comment: At the minimum, you should include what sort of error you gotten ...

Comment: I suggest you paste the codes here.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `trigger_error()` in PHP for debugging instead of echo. Then you don't have to worry about output buffering, etc.

```
trigger_error("I have reached checkpoint 1!", E_USER_WARNING);
```

Put a tail -f on your error log for your web server and see how far you get.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php